# How can I create a dynamic join between 2 SQL Server tables on 2 different servers?

Tags: sql-server

I have data in 2 SQL Server 2012 database servers. I need to create a view containing data from both servers.

My first step was to import the join-table from Server2 into Server1 and create the view. The problem is though, that I need to keep the exported table up-to-date and thus a static "export" of the table is not ideal.

What methods could I use in order to create a dynamic join between 2 tables on 2 different servers?

Answer (score 2):

You could establish [linked server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff772782.aspx) and use 4 part names:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.my_view
AS
SELECT * -- cols list
FROM dbo.table_name t
JOIN server_name.database_name.schema_name.table_name c
  ON t.id = c.id;
```

Note:

1. If view will be part of transaction, MS DTC (distributed transaction coordinator) should be enabled.
2. Depending how you build your query, performance may be degraded.
3. Not every type can be used (like `XML`)